# How to hide/show drill down subreports in Jaspersoft Community Edition?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report which has a main report, and would have a second detail band which would be a subreport call to another jrxml file.

The report and subreport are showing properly. But now i want to hide the subreport on load and would only show up when the statement no is clicked and be hidden when clicked again, is there some javascript/jquery trick i could add into jasper?

```
sample:

id    statement_no    name           company
1     123-4           John Carp      Carp Solutions
   statement_no     type    amount
   123-4            BILL    456.12
   123-4            CHARGE  14.05 

2     145-9           Jenny Jones    Alias Investments
3     111-2           Lo Yee         Alain Bank
   statement_no     type    amount
   111-2            BILL    150.00
   111-2            CHARGE  2.00
```

**note:** I am using the Community edition which does not support Visualize.js

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the report to be interactive? This is not possible as far as I know.